# how to encode raw json string in php

Tags: php, json

I have JSON that has been saved in a text box on my site to a database below.

```
{&quot;@type&quot;:&quot;GOOOGLE.COM&quot;,&quot;@id&quot;:&quot;GOOGLE&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;GOOGLE&quot;,&quot;inLanguage&quot;:&quot;en-US&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;dfghjk | Bloomberg Professional Services&quot;,&quot;isPartOf&quot;:{&quot;@id&quot;:&quot;GOOGLE,&quot;datePublished&quot;:&quot;2020-02-11T21:51:45+00:00&quot;,&quot;dateModified&quot;:&quot;2020-02-11T21:51:45+00:00&quot;}]}
```

I want to convert it to look properly in PHP as so:

```
{"@type":"GOOOGLE.COM","@id":"GOOGLE","url":"GOOGLE","inLanguage":"en-US","name":"dfghjk | Bloomberg Professional Services","isPartOf":{"@id":"GOOGLE,"datePublished":"2020-02-11T21:51:45+00:00","dateModified":"2020-02-11T21:51:45+00:00"}]}
```

I tried doing a json_encode but its not working. How do i convert that string with all those escape quotes etc to a normal json string in PHP?

I tried as so:

```
  $str = "{&quot;@type&quot;:&quot;GOOOGLE.COM&quot;,&quot;@id&quot;:&quot;GOOGLE&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;GOOGLE&quot;,&quot;inLanguage&quot;:&quot;en-US&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;dfghjk | Bloomberg Professional Services&quot;,&quot;isPartOf&quot;:{&quot;@id&quot;:&quot;GOOGLE,&quot;datePublished&quot;:&quot;2020-02-11T21:51:45+00:00&quot;,&quot;dateModified&quot;:&quot;2020-02-11T21:51:45+00:00&quot;}]}"
  $data = json_encode($str, true);  
  return $data;
```

Comment: Even after decoding the HTML entities, there are still a couple of syntax errors in there - the nested `"GOOGLE` value isn't quoted properly, and there's a spare `]` at the end. It'll need fixing manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode HTML entities back into characters:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

```
  $json = htmlspecialchars_decode($str, true);  // valid json string
  $data = json_decode($json); // convert json to php data structure
  return $data;
```

Comment: didnt seem to work, in the end it comes out to null and using the debugger i see it doesnt change

Comment: looks like `$json = htmlspecialchars_decode($str, true);` should just be `$json = htmlspecialchars_decode($str);`

Comment: also, the provided JSON string is not a valid JSON. A few quotes are misplaced

Comment: Gotcha,is there a way i can remove the outside quotes as well and replace them with single? `"{"@type":"GOOOGLE.COM","@id":"GOOGLE","url":"GOOGLE","inLanguage":"en-US","name":"dfghjk | Bloomberg Professional Services","isPartOf":{"@id":"GOOGLE,"datePublished":"2020-02-11T21:51:45+00:00","dateModified":"2020-02-11T21:51:45+00:00"}]}"`

Comment: JSON standard uses double-quotes for strings.If you convert double quotes with singe, that will break the json even further. I do not think there is a one-fits-all solution to repair broken JSON.

Comment: It ended up working in the end when i used valid JSON.